# How to set a line between begin and end?

Tags: rules, algorithm2e

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}

\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\LinesNumbered

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,fancyhdr,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx,environ,amsmath,amssymb}
   \begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \textbf{Input} : An a $p^t$, prime $p$, 
     integer $t$ and data s above\;
    \textbf{Find} : A swq $G$\;
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \textbf{begin}\;

    \hspace{0.5cm} $L =\phi;B=\phi$\;
    \hspace{0.5cm} repeat\;
    \hspace{1cm} select largest ord$_G(a)$\;
    \hspace{1cm} $B=B\cup \{a\}$\;
    \hspace{1cm} $L^{'} $\;
   \hspace{1cm} \textbf{for} (each $b \in L^{'}$) remove all elements in 
   $U(b)$ from $M$\;
  \hspace{1cm} $L=L\cup L^{'}$\;
  \hspace{0.5cm} until $(\sum_{a_j \in B}R(a_j) =t)$\;
  \textbf{end}



     \caption{Algorithm}
     \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

**Question :** How to design a vertical line between begin and end statement of the algorithm?

See the output:

[image]

Comment: For the future: Please format pasted code with the respective markdown. This increases readability ba a LOT :)

Comment: For Ravens comment: Hint if using a browser, you can highlight the code and hit Ctrl-k to get it formatted this way.

Comment: @daleif I do Ctrl-k but it works only for the first line of the code.

Comment: @regarding the formatting of code in questions: Select the block of code first and then press Ctrl+k or the `{}` button. Regarding your question: You might want to use `\Begin`,  `\End` , `\Input`,... instead of `\textbf{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the keywords defined by [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Here's a better markup that does just that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInOut{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{KwFind}{Find}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwInput{An a $p^t$, prime $p$, integer $t$ and data s above}
  \KwFind{A swq $G$}
  \BlankLine
  \Begin{
    $L = \phi$; $B = \phi$\;
    \Repeat{$\sum_{a_j \in B} R(a_j) = t$}{
      select largest $\mathrm{ord}_G(a)$\;
      $B = B \cup \{a\}$\;
      $L'$\;
      \For{each $b \in L'$}{
        remove all elements in $U(b)$ from $M$\;
      }
      $L = L \cup L'$\;
    }
  }
  \caption{Algorithm caption}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```